# How to get element from Java's LinkedList in constant time using HashMap

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap, iterator

In Java, is there way I can get an element from LinkedList collection
at constant time if I can store the position where the element is inserted into the list? I can't use an ArrayList as I want to delete items from the middle of the list at Constant time.

LinkedList's [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)) accepts int as an argument and the complexity is O(N).

In C++, I can use a map to store the iterator of the list. To access any element at constant time, I can lookup the element in the hash table and get the iterator to it. Using the iterator I can get to that entry in the list.

1. How can I achieve a similar functionality in Java?
2. Can we store iterator in HashMap's value and use that to directly access an element?

Here is a code snippet that shows how I can do it in C++. This program doesn't require both LinkedList and HashMap. But imagine something like an LRU Cache or a different scenario where I want to maintain a list as well as a map.

```
list<string> namesList;
unordered_map<string, list<string>::iterator> namesMap;

namesList.push_front("hello");
namesMap["hello"] = namesList.begin();

namesList.push_front("hi");
namesMap["hi"] = namesList.begin();

namesList.push_front("abc");
namesMap["abc"] = namesList.begin();

// Now to access "hi" on the list, I can just look it up on the map
// Get iterator to "hi" from the map and access it
auto itr = namesMap.find("hi");
if (itr != namesMap.end())
{
    // This is a simple case where my list is just storing the key
    cout << *(itr->second) << endl;
}
```

Comment: But I want to delete items from the middle of the list in constant time.

Comment: Why not just use the `Map`, and drop the list? If you want to preserve insertion order, use `LinkedHashMap` would do that.

Comment: The example I added does not require a list. But imagine something like an LRU Cache or a different scenario where I want to maintain a list as well as a map. Do I have an option other than implementing a doubly linked list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.LinkedHashMap` sounds like exactly what you want (including the LRU case). For more elaborate caching situations, you probably want `com.google.common.cache.Cache` from the Guava library.

There is no way to store a pointer to a specific node in a Java `LinkedList`, and in fact `LinkedList` is a pretty useless implementation -- even Josh Bloch who wrote it doesn't recommend it anymore. If your needs are more specialized than what `LinkedList` and `LinkedHashMap` can handle, then you should probably just build your own linked list implementation -- it's literally the simplest data structure to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah LinkedList is simple to implement. I was more curious to know if Java has some way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap has better performance to find elements than a List, always. 
It is a limitation of the data structure itself.

In Java you can implement a Hashmap to get any elements at constant time.
But in a List the best algorithm to search elements in a List (sorted list)
is a Binary Search that cost O(log n).